# Magento Hooks - Will Magento allow me to do this?

Tags: magento

I'm going to be starting a E-Commerce project and the client is interested in using Magento.  In this project, when a customer adds something to the cart, I'll need to pull them out of the flow, where they'll proceed through a custom `wizard-esque` area.

They basically design a document using a drag and drop interface.  After they finish, that document will be saved as a `PDF`, and I want them redirected to checkout

So my questions are

1. Does Magento have hooks available for `after an item is added to the
   cart` ?
2. If I pull them away to this other section of the site (Wizard
   portion), changes they make will potentially `add costs` to
   their cart.  Would I still have access to products, prices, and the
   cart so that I can continue to modify their cart until they return
   to checkout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento users Event-Observer pattern, where you can hook into virtually any action which is performed and execute your custom code,

Refer to below links,

```
http://inchoo.net/category/ecommerce/magento/events-observers/
https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/6973324
http://huztechbuzz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/complete-list-of-all-events-in-magento/
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
```

So you have to figure out which event you can use and plugin your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as i remember all the cart info ( products/prices ) is stored in the $_SESSION. So you can get all the information from there you need, modify it via your so-called wizzard and udpate the session information after that!

Cheers! :)